# Symfony 5 $form->isSubmitted() Returning False for File Upload

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I am attempting to upload a file via an API endpoint controller I have created:

```
/**
 * @Route("/upload", methods="POST")
 */
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(UserFileType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if (!$form->isSubmitted()) {
        dd($request->files->get('file'));
    }
   ...
```

The `dd($request->files->get('file'))` is showing my file as expected so I am unclear why `isSubmitted()` is returning false when the method is receiving `multipart/form-data` `POST` request with data. I am submitting the `POST` request via `Postman`. Why is the form not submitted?

UserFileType:

```
class UserFileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', FileType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '2M',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'application/pdf',
                            'application/x-pdf',
                        ],
                        'maxSizeMessage' => 'The file size must not exceed {{ limit }} {{ suffix }}.',
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'The file type {{ type }} is not valid',
                    ])
                ],
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: What is `UserFileType`? There could be a mismatch in the fields defined there and that in your request. Either that or a mismatch in the method on the `UserFileType` form class.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule please see edit adding UserFileType.

Comment: What do you get setting the form method when building the form in `UserFileType`? `$builder->setMethod('POST')->add('...')`

Comment: After adding ->setMethod('POST') to $builder and posting the file isSubmitted still returns false

Comment: Could you check `$form->getErrors()` output and add it if necessary please.

Comment: @Lounis dd($form->getErrors()) is returning empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For form classes derived from `AbstractType`, the form is named using [`fqcnToBlockPrefix`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.2.1/src/Symfony/Component/Form/AbstractType.php#L53) when [it's built through `FormFactory`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.2.1/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php#L50).

You can confirm this by dumping `$form->getName()`.

Now, `$form->handleRequest` method as implemented performs a number of checks through the [request handler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.2.1/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php#L41) before submitting the form.

1. [Checks the method matches that of the form](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.2.1/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php#L50)
2. [Checks the name of the form is present in the request if the form has a name](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.2.1/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php#L88)
3. [Checks that at least one of the form fields are filled if the form has no name](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.2.1/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php#L105)

Your form is not submitting through the request handler `handleRequest` method because fields in the request are not properly mapped together with your form name.

You have to map the form name in your HTTP POST request in following way:

```
[ "user_file" =>  [ "file" => <uploaded file> ] ]
```

This may prove to not be straight forward in Postman.
Therefore I recommend to implement your form as a nameless form instead by overriding `getBlockPrefix` to return an empty string.

```php
class UserFileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //...
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first SO thread that comes up for the keywords `handlerequest issubmitted false`, I thought I would share what worked for my team on an adjacent issue.

We were getting a `false` response when doing a `PATCH` request. We eventually realized that we were neglecting to pass `Request::METHOD_PATCH` in the `method` option when creatin the form. Putting in a ternary statement that set that value was enough to solve our problem.

I hope this helps someone.